# Definite Integration

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the mean value of voltage $V=220 \sin(140\pi t)$ over the range $t = 0$ to $t = 3.6ms$

I have found this formula.

$$A=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

And got this far.

$$\frac{1}{3.6} \int_0^{3.6} 220 \sin(140 \pi t) \, dt$$

But now I am stuck. As I have not found a way shown with the $220 \sin(140 \pi t)$. They always show how to do it without sin.

Could anyone hep me?

Comment: Are you asking whats the integral for $\sin (\pi t) $?

Comment: Hint:  Let $u = 140\pi t$.

Comment: Yes. I have not seen a way to do it where there is sin in the formula. And have got really confused about it. I have been trying for hours to find a way to find the mean value of the voltage.

Comment: Derivative of $-\cos(Cx)=C\sin(Cx)$ where $C$ is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $u \mapsto 140 \pi t$ and factor the constant out of the integral,

\begin{align*}
 &= \frac{220}{3.6} \int_0^{140\cdot \pi \cdot 3.6} \frac{\sin u}{140 \pi} \, du \\
&= \frac{220}{140(3.6)\pi} \left[ {-\cos u} \right]_0^{140(3.6)\pi} \\
&= \frac{220}{504 \pi} \left[ -\cos (504\pi) + \cos(0) \right] \\
&= \frac{220}{504\pi} \cdot(0) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Here is a page about [substitution in integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). For this problem with the general, $\int \sin (kx) \, dx$, we can substitute $u \mapsto kx$ and then $dx = \frac{du}{k}$. Using this we can rewrite the integral as $\int \frac{\sin u}{k} \, du = \frac 1 k \int \sin u\,du$. Now since $\int \sin t\,dt = -\cos t + c$, we get as our final answer, $-\frac{1}{k}\cos u + c = -\frac 1 k \cos (kx) + c $.

Comment: Thank you. I really need to learn about it. I will have a look at the page. I just got so confused. Is that the full workings out you have done? Is the mean value .5.13215 x 10 ^{-15}.

Comment: @Liam See my edits. I multiplied out $140 \cdot 3.6 \cdot \pi$ and put the resulting decimal into the cosine function not realizing $140 \cdot 3.6$ was an integer so the cosine function is $-1$ there, making the final answer zero. So before I had something really close to zero, but not zero due to precision errors, but zero is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This will make me understand it more.

Answer (score 2):

Remember you can pull the coefficient of $220\sin(140 \pi t)$ out in front of the integral. So you would get
$$\frac{220}{3.6} \int_{0}^{3.6} \sin(140 \pi t) \,dt$$

As a hint as to how to integrate $\sin(140 \pi t)$, remember that
$$\int \sin(at) \,dt = -\frac{1}{a} \cos(at)$$

for any scalar $a$. In your case, $a = 140 \pi$. Once you have the integral, evaluate it from $t = 0$ to $t = 3.6$, and that will be your answer.